# Получить часть массива

Tags: php, yahoo

[Сам массив](http://ideone.com/x68OUG) (слишком большой, чтобы поместить сюда). Нужно вывести description (163 строчка).

Массив получаю api запросом

```
<?php
    $query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="nome, ak")';
    $api_request = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&format=json";
    $result = file_get_contents($api_request);
    $result_decode = json_decode($result);
    echo '<pre>' . var_export($result_decode, true) . '</pre>';
```

Я так понимаю, нужно использовать `array_keys($result [])`, но что брать в качестве значения для поиска?

Comment: вариант `$result_decode->query->results->channel->item->description` не работает?

Comment: Спасибо! Работает! Только остаются кавычки http://ideone.com/Dv4J1h (1 и 34 строка)...

Comment: Можно ли убрать ненужные кавычки с помощью str_replace(), или есть более оптимальный вариант?

Comment: у вас там кавычки рисуются, потому что через var_export выводите переменную. Это строка вот ив кавычках. Сама по себе переменная не содержит их. Можете проверить и вывести ее через print, echo и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но остается вот эти квадратные скобки (http://imgur.com/4ftZnGz), вывожу вот так echo ($result_decode->query->results->channel->item->description)

Comment: я вам скажу, там кроме `]]>` в конце есть еще и `<![CDATA[` в начале (: удаляйте реплейсом.

Comment: @teran я добавил ответ к вопросу, как по Вашему, сойдет решение?

Comment: `<![CDATA[` в начале то тоже убрать надо (гляньте выводимый исходный html-код)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php   
    $query = 'select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="'.$_POST['city'].', ak")';
    $api_request = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&format=json";
    $result = file_get_contents($api_request);
    $result_decode = json_decode($result);
    $description = $result_decode->query->results->channel->item->description; //получаю нужную часть массива
    $weather = stristr($description,']]>',true); //убираю ненужные символы в конце
    echo $weather;
```